# Typescript compiler errors not generating when referencing method in other module

Tags: typescript

I am new to Typescript and am having trouble triggering compiler warnings from a separate file:

I have the following interface I have defined in `file1.ts`

```
interface ISettings
{
    setting1 : number;
    setting2 : string;
}
```

If I use this in a method signature the compiler correctly generates an error when called with parameters with types that do not match the interface

```
public async updateSettings(settingsDictionary : ISettings
{
}

params = { setting1: "a string", setting2: 10 } 
Thing.updateSettings(params); // generates compiler error
```

My questions is how I can get the compiler to complain if I call this method from a different file than where the interface is defined.  Right now I have a test file say `file1.test.ts` that includes this module.  When I call this method with invalid params no compiler error is generated.

Comment: Could you please share minimum reproducable code example? It will be much easier for other folks to figure out whats happening.

Comment: Remember to `export` appropriately when using modules.